# Primary key and constraints on partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a large table with more than 10 million rows which take around a minute to query out the result although it has indexes for all the 3 columns.

I have tried to do list partition, but the partitioned table does not allow me to create primary key and foreign key which are needed. Is there a way to create those constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrade to postgres 12, which supports both of these.  That said, a table with 10 million rows is not all that big and I would look into improving your query performance before partitioning, unless you are expecting it to grow rapidly.

Comment: I have a plain query that returns all the columns and more than 30% of the rows with just a single condition. I couldn't find a way to optimize it other than indexes(which is already being used on the query).

Comment: If you are returning 3 million rows, that is almost certainly the bottleneck and partitioning is unlikely to help with that.

Comment: Are there any feasible options to try out for this scenario ?